# Android: Is it possible to add any library created in any language into the Android project?

Tags: android

Suppose I find some source code that is designed to be compiled and run on a Windows machine and provide some ML solution to face detection. I now need a face detection application for android. What are the steps that I need to take so that I can add this source code as library to my android application, and make use of these features?

Comment: You do realize that [ML Kit face detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection) is available. Otherwise decide if cloud or on-device detection. And if on-device figure out if the solution you found can be shrunk to fit mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If its compiled, you could probably just add it to your assets folder and execute good old bash with System.exec() or something.